# Dynamics CRM iframes

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

Is it possible with javascript to dynamically add iframes to one form?

We have a form with one Notes tab, so for each new note the user can attach a document. What we need is: for each note that has an attached document, to have an iframe with the document in read-only mode. I already know how to prevent some users to download the attached files.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two web resources to do that. One web resource needs to fetch all notes (with attachments) related to current entity and display them somehow (perhaps an HTML ordered list). You can use [SDK.REST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427(v=crm.7).aspx) to do this.

When the user clicks on one of the items in the list, [the note attachment is fetched](http://scaleablesolutions.com/download-notes-attachments-using-javascript-and-rest/) and another web resource would be popped up over the form (with [Alert.JS](https://alertjs.codeplex.com/documentation#Alert.showWebResource)) once the file is fully retrieved.

That second web resource could display the received contents.